# How to target ESNext modules on Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I am asked to target ESNext modules on my Nuxt app, how can I do that? I could not find anything on the web.

[image]

Related to this issue: https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/pull/107#issuecomment-939443776

Comment: Why not asking there directly? Also, please link the actual issue rather than posting an image of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the freshly released Nuxt v3 beta, we can see that ESmodules are only partially supported in Nuxt2.
You should probably wait/upgrade to Nuxt3.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

checking the documentation itself, I found no reports of support for ES Modules, however, it is known that "vitejs/vite (vue)" and VueJS 3 via Command Line support these modules, I believe the Nuxt community needs to create a project template with this setting is built into the project settings.

Comment: This is weird actually because it does support ESModules in the src so why not node modules too?